# Can you Compare things you like and don't like

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Can you compare liking and not liking something. 
Example: I liked her yesterday but today I don't

Comment: If that’s your example then clearly you can.

Answer (score 1):

***Yes***, of course you can.

*Liking* entails an emotional involvement and is something that can change over time.

I *hate* going to the gym in the summer, for example, but I absolutely *like* it in the winter.

Another thing you may do: *like* and *dislike* something or someone at the same time.

"I like her because she's my childhood friend, but I don't like her in the sense that she steals."

So in that example, you're comparing two feelings, both liking and disliking.

Is that what you're asking, or am I misunderstanding?